# Aggregating Views and conditional field

Tags: views

I have created a **views** for label printing;

[image]

1st item in the row is **name**,

2nd item in the row is **address**,

3rd row is **city**,

4th row is **state**,

5th row is **Country**.

All of them are fields of type contact.

Now I want two things;

1. If country is **India**, then it should not be displayed.
2. If two records has same **Address** & **city** & **State** & **Country** they should be aggregated.

Comment: for first option you can use filter.. if *field* **not equal to** *value*

Comment: Then it hides hole row not the country name.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Views Conditional Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional) you can set conditions for fields . The other module which may become useful is [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view).

Here are some description about Views Conditional Module :

> Views Conditional is a simple module that allows you to define conditionals (if xxx then yyy)
>   with fields in views. Conditions include:
>
> - Equal To
> - Not Equal To
> - Greater Than
> - Less Than
> - Empty
> - Not Empty
>
> Views conditional allows you to output text based on the result of the condition.

Answer (score 0):

The module I use for aggregation is [Views Aggregator Plus](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_aggregator) and it offers functions that run after the SQL query, altering the results with PHP. It's a lightweight and easy to use method.